# Combining three text files into one text file forming a sentence C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, function, computer-science

I am trying to create a program in C++ using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. The main purpose of this program is to read three different files(headlines1,headlines2, and headlines3) and put them all together to form a single file and creating a sentence within that output file. I have figured out a function that I could use, but this function only reads and prints the 3 files out onto the console window. When I try to change the `cout` statement into an outfile, my outfile that I created is blank... I don't know what to do or how to structure the code.

```
    #include<fstream>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    void readingFile(string[], ifstream &); //Funtion Prototype
    int main()
    {
    string header1[50], header2[50], header3[50]; //Declaring array with 50 elements

    int size1, size2, size3;

    ifstream Fin, Fin2, Fin3;
    ofstream Fout;

    Fin.open("Headlines1.txt");   //Reading from these 3 files.
    Fin2.open("Headlines2.txt");
    Fin3.open("Headlines3.txt");
    if (!Fin || !Fin2 || !Fin3)    //Checking for unsuccessful open
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
        cin.ignore();
        return 1;
    }

    Fout.open("testingHeadlines.txt");  //Used for unsuccessful opening output
    if (!Fout)
    {
        cout << "Output file opening failed.\n";
        cin.ignore();
        return 2;
    }

    cout << "Building.... Editing....\n" << endl;
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "Headlines file 1 below:\n" << endl;
    readingFile(header1, Fin);  //Function call
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Headlines file 2 below:\n" << endl;
    readingFile(header2, Fin2); //Function call
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Headlines file 3 below:\n" << endl;
    readingFile(header3, Fin3); //Function call
    cout << endl << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
    }

    //the function 'readingFile' 
    //Pre-conditions: Reads the contents from the files of Headlines1,2,and 3
    //Post-conditions: Prints out the contents.
    void readingFile(string[], ifstream &infile)
    {   
    char next;
    infile.get(next);
        while (!infile.eof())  //Reading until EndOfFile
        {
            cout << next;    //Problem is here?? I would think.
            infile.get(next);
        }
     }
```

I'm just not certain if where I said the "Problem is here??" is where the problem is at. Every time I change the cout to outfile(I know, I have to change the parameters within the function header) once doing that I open the outfile and the file is blank.

All the files contain random words/phrases and when put together they will make a sentence. For ex. Headlines1 contains **'***Queen Jennifer***'** Headlines2 contains **'***has brain surgery***'** Headlines3 contains **'***after eating 30 jalapenos.***'** and When put together it **should read** '*Queen Jennifer has brain surgery after eating 30 jalapenos.*' but the files contain more words/ phrases that what I just listed in my example.

When I run the program above I am able to read all three Headline files, but they are printed in up to down form. For example, my output on my console screen would be:

Queen

Jennifer

has brain surgery

after eating 30 jalapenos

**Problem:**
Getting my headlines to read from left to right.

Getting them into a output file instead of the console screen.

Help Please.

Comment: `system("cat file1 file2 file3")`;

Comment: Other than opening it when do you ever use your `Fout` file in this code?

Answer (score 3):

You could replace this...

```
void readingFile(string[], ifstream &infile)
{   
    char next;
    infile.get(next);
    while (!infile.eof())  //Reading until EndOfFile
    {
        cout << next;    //Problem is here?? I would think.
        infile.get(next);
    }
}
```

...and the calls there-to, such as...

```
readingFile(header1, Fin);
```

...with this...

```
void readingFile(ifstream& infile, ofstream& fout)
{   
    char next;
    while (infile.get(next))  //Reading until EndOfFile or error
        if (next != '\n') // if not newline
           fout << next;    // stream to file
}
```

...and calls ala...

```
readingFile(Fin, Fout);
```

That way `readingFile` is told where to write the output, and filters out the newline characters that were causing the output to appear on different lines.

Comment: Yes! This worked! Thank you so much! But I am currently running into another problem which is. The whole contents in the file is now on one line, just like I wanted, but It's all on one line. How could I make it to the point where 'Queen Jennifer'

Comment: @CesarEscobar: looks like your sentence got chopped off... my guess is you want to replace the newline with an extra space... just add an `else fout << ' ';` after the `fout << next;`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Open the three files.
    std::ifstream file_1("Headlines1.txt");
    std::ifstream file_2("Headlines2.txt");
    std::ifstream file_3("Headlines3.txt");

    // Combine into one string.
    std::string content;
    content += std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file_1),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    content += std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file_2),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    content += std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file_3),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    // Output the string into a single file.
    std::ofstream output_file("testingHeadlines.txt");
    output_file << content;
}
```

I'm not sure what you're wanting to do about spacing between files, but that shouldn't be too hard for you to fine-tune this code for.

Answer (score 0):

one possible thing why your ouput is like this is that `std::ifstream::get()` that you used in `infile.get(next)` is a non-formatted reading method which means it will not skip white spaces and newline character `\n` by default. so you need to check if `next` value is a newline like this:

`if(next == '\n') continue ;`

before passing it to `cout << next`. Thus you will skip printing a newline in your console screen.